# Keep getting a "cannot read property error

Tags: javascript

keep getting the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at setDate" not sure what im missing!!!

```
 <script>
        const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-Hand');
        const minsHand = document.querySelector('.min-Hand');
        const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-Hand');

        function setDate(){
          const now = new Date();

          const seconds = now.getSeconds();
          const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
          secondHand.style.transform = rotate(`${secondsDegrees}deg`);
          console.log(seconds);

          const mins = now.getMinutes();
          const minsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
          hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`
        }

        setInterval(setDate, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Where in your page is that script? Do you run it before the page has loaded?

Comment: Either your `secondHand` or `hourHand` variables are undefined (or not what you think they are) when you run this script. So it errors out when it cannot find the `style` attribute on these.

Comment: @adr5240, they're `null` according to the error message. `querySelector` returns `null`, not `undefined`, when no element was found.

Comment: Either way; calling `.style` on `null` or `undefined` will give you that error. You need to check the timing of the function so that the HTML is set before you run this OR you can add a check before calling `.style`. Something like `if(secondHand) {secondHand.style = whatever}`

Answer (score 2):

Your querySelectors are probably wrong .second-Hand maybe should be .second-hand and your minutes are wrong, also backticks should goes like this:

```
secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;
```

```
const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
const minsHand = document.querySelector('.min-hand');
const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();

  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;

  const mins = now.getMinutes();
  const minsDegrees = ((mins / 60) * 360) + ((seconds/60)*6) + 90;
  minsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`;
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)